# Gender in personifications

Tags: gender

I'm wondering what the consensus is regarding the gender of personified nouns. I think that rather than trying to describe the question in more detail, an example will do the job way better:

Which of the two following variants is considered to be the correct one?

> 1. die Geschichte als Lehrer

or

> 2. die Geschichte als Lehrerin

I wanted to say "history as a teacher", so because *Geschichte* is of feminine gender I wondered whether it would be better to use *Lehrer* or *Lehrerin* here.

Answer (score 3):

## Personifications of Abstract Ideas are usually feminin

There is a long tradition of assigning the female gender to personifications. Just a couple of examples:

1. The very most of national personifications are women: [Bharat Mata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharat_Mata), Britannica, [Germania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germania_(personification))
2. In German law, all legal entities are addressed with a female gender. So, in trial, it is *die Klägerin* ("the claimant") and *die Beklagte* ("the defendant") as soon as these are legal entities.
3. In Middle High German, they had the personification of *Frau Welt* ("Lady Woman").
4. Socialist parties are addressed as feminin:

> Die Partei muß ihre Reihen zusammenschließen und als Führerin der Massen handeln.<sup>[1]</sup>

> Die Sozialistische Partei gibt sich als Verfechterin der marxistischen Lehren aus;<sup>[2]</sup>

> In Wirklichkeit ist diese Sozialistische Partei, die sich Führerin und Lehrerin der Massen nennt, [...]. <sup>[2]</sup>

5. Is seems to be common to use female personifications for abstract entities such as "Philosophie", "Literatur", "Musik":

> Richtig ist, die Literatur war für ihn eine Schwester der Krankheit und eine Trösterin des Alters.<sup>[3]</sup>

> Musik ist eine Bändigerin des Tierischen, eine Trösterin bedrückter Herzen, eine Schöpferin des Frohsinns, eine priesterliche Erzieherin der Menschenseele.<sup>[4]</sup>

## Die Geschichte als Lehrerin

In your case, I would prefer to say

> Die Geschichte als Lehrerin.

This would fit into the tradition of assigning feminin personifications and allegories to abstract ideas. Since "Geschichte" is an abstract idea, I see a strong argument for membership to this family of personifications, which I have listed as 5th group above.

It also sounds more natural to align the gender of the personification with the gender of the notion that is being personified.

The user [David Vogt](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/35111/david-vogt) mentioned in a comment, that there is a Latin phrase from Cicero<sup>[5]</sup>

> Historia Magistra Vitae [History is the teacher of life.]

which has a personification of history, which happens to have female gender in Latin, which is also transferred to the gender of the attribution *Magistra* is the feminin form, while *Magister* would be the masculin form. This would be translated as:

> Geschichte ist die Lehrmeisterin des Lebens.

So, this is an example of use of a personification of *Geschichte* which would be explicitely assigned a female gender. I consider this a strong backing for my argument above.

---

[1]: Clara Zetkin: *Rede zu Ehren Lenins auf dem Sowjetkongreß der UdSSR in Moskau*, quoted as in: https://www.marxists.org/deutsch/archiv/zetkin/1924/01/ehrenrede.html

[2]: Antonio Gramsci: *Die kommunistische Partei*. quoted as in https://www.marxists.org/deutsch/archiv/gramsci/1920/09/kompartei.html

[3]: https://www.zeit.de/1959/04/zwischen-menuetten-und-enzyklopaedien/seite-2

[4]: Ganghofer, Ludwig: *Lebenslauf eines Optimisten*. In: Simons, Oliver (Hg.) Deutsche Autobiographien 1690-1930, Berlin: Directmedia Publ. 2004 [1911], S. 26214, quoted from https://www.dwds.de/wb/Tr%C3%B6sterin

[5]: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_magistra_vitae

Comment: However, it has to be said that in earlier times, when personifications of this type were more popular, *Lehrerin* was considered too mundane (or maybe not yet in common use). *Lehrmeisterin* seems to have been the apposite term: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_magistra_vitae.

Comment: Du meinst die GmbH, die AG, usw.? Aber: der Verein, der Vorstand, der Ausschuss, das Konsortium, das Kartell, .... . Welche Endung bekommen denn sächliche Abstraktionen?

Comment: @userunknown Falls du dich auf 2. beziehst, also auf die Personifikationen im Recht: Alle juristischen Personen werden mit dem femininum angesprochen. Also auch wenn ein Verein klagt, handelt es sich um eine Klägerin. vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kl%C3%A4ger

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Tja, das steht da, aber stimmt es auch? Eine Begründung steht nicht dabei - wg. "die juristische Person"? Ich dekoriere ein Konsortium jedenfalls mit dem neutralen Artikel, ganz egal, was die Juristen machen. Und zu 4.(spitzfindig): Ist/war der Kommunistische Bund keine sozialistische Partei? :) (KB, KBW) War vielleicht nicht als Partei verfasst, das könnte sein.

Comment: @userunknown Du argumentierst am Thema vorbei. Es geht nicht darum, welchen Artikel Worte bekommen, sondern ob Personifikationen von Entitäten, die keinen Sexus haben, weiblich sein können.

Comment: Wie in meiner aktualisierten Antwort dargestellt hätte ich die Frage für Justitia derart verstanden, aber Personifikationen der Geschichte sind mir nicht geläufig. Deswegen stellte sich mir die Lage so dar, dass sich die Personifikation von Geschichte nur am Geschlecht des Wortes festmacht. Der Wikipediaartikel zur Personifikation hat ein Beispiel von Personifikationen von Mond und Sonne, aber da der Künstler aus einem Sprachraum (Italien) kommt, in dem das Geschlecht dieser konträr zum Deutschen ist, hat dieser die Sonne männlich und den Mond weiblich dargestellt.Seine Wahl liegt aber  …

Comment: … an nichts anderem als dem sprachlichen Geschlecht in seiner Sprache. Dort herrscht die strukturell gleiche, aber im Konkreten eben oft unterschiedliche, willkürliche Geschlechtszuordnung vor und daher die nämliche Konfusion von Sexus und Genus. Aus der Sprache folgt nicht, dass die Inkarnation der Geschichte weiblich sein muss (siehe: Person). Daher wäre "Die Geschichte war seine Lehrerin" Unfug, gäbe es keine kanonifizierte Ikonografie der Geschichte, die auf eine historisch willkürliche Entscheidung zurückgeht.

Answer (score 0):

Many people confuse the linguistic gender with the biological sex. Of course, Geschichte doesn't have a sex, therefore it can't be treated as a female Person and hence, it doesn't get a female suffix.

> Die Katze als Raubtier ist ein geschickter Jäger.

The cat is a female genericum and used for female and male cats, Raubtier is neutrum and doesn't even offer a female ending, and the hunter is a generic masculinum.

> Die Katzenmutter ist nach dem Wurf eine besonders vorsichtige Jägerin.

This is possible, while not neccessary, to underline the female nature of the animal.

> Bundeskanzler Kohl ist inzwischen Geschichte.

Here, it doesn't matter again, that the linguistic gender switches from male to female. Words have a linguistic gender, every noun has, but it does not carry meaning, and it is bound to the word, not to the entity, which it points to.

#### Update:

David Vogt mentions in a comment the ancient habit, to personify not only by language, but with drawings and sculpture, and in such a culture, and therefore for persons, dealing with such cultures on a regular basis, it can be natural, to associate certain personifications with images with of a canonical form. For Justizia, the personification of justice, the image as a woman with a balance and a sword is pretty common, even nowadays. For Geschichte, I don't have such a picture before my eye.

For persons with stong bindings to the cultural sector, that might vary, and they may have a certain form of visualization in mind, which might always be female, and then, the transformation of that image to an image of a female teacher is natural.

Since the question didn't focus on traditional image or the cultural sector in particular, I don't recall my answer. There are words, for which there is no ancient, established iconification. And there are words with neutral gender - how should they be personified, since there is no neutral sex?

> Das Missverständnis als (Vater/Mutter) des Konflikt …

> Das Orchester als Botschafter(in?) des Friedens …

Bei Berufen und anderen Substantivierungen von Verben ist es naheliegend, beim Geschlecht der generischen Form zu bleiben, die kein Geschlecht nahelegt (Schreiner, Programmierer, Esser, Träumer, ...). Das Deutsche kennt keine Kongruenz des Geschlechts über unterschiedliche Satzglieder, wie das Beispiel mit der Katze oben zeigt, aber hier wären weitere:

> Der Minister(m.) als Person (f.) der Zeitgeschichte ….

> Als Trainer(m.) ist meine Tochter (f.) …

> Seine Frau (f.) ist Mitglied (n.) beim FC.

> Sein Weib (n.) ist Präsident (m.) eines Rockerclubs.

Bei Personifikationen ist eine Sonderregel nicht gerechtfertigt, außer es gibt eine kanonifizierte Visualisierung der Personifikation, wie dies bei der Germania, der Justizia, und wie ich lernen musste, der Geschichte, je nach kulturellem Horizont, der Fall ist.

Comment: *Geschichte doesn't have a sex, therefore it can't be threatened as a female Person*. That's not true. The question asks about personification. That is a case where history can absolutely be treated as a female person, as Boethius did for [Pp]hilosophy: *Accordingly, when I had lifted my eyes and fixed my gaze upon her, I beheld my nurse, Philosophy.*

Comment: It is not true, that the _-in_ suffix would be only used when there is biological sex. For instance in law, they use _die Klägerin_ ("the claimant"), whenever the linguistic gender of the claimant is feminin - these can be legal entities which are not persons. So, the argument in the first three sentences of your post is insufficient at least, if not wrong. That's why I give -1 here.

Comment: Also, none of the examples is having a personification. I guess, personifications are a special case of gender use.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Die Frage ist doch, wieso Geschichte als weiblicher Lehrer personifiziert werden soll. Im Englischen gibt es nur einen Artikel, "the nurse" muss es folglich heißen, daher kommt der Artikel zur Geschlechtsbestimmung nicht in Betracht. Es muss also einen anderen Grund geben, von "the nurse" auf "her" zu schließen.

Comment: Wo wird hier geschlossen? Dem Boethius erscheint eine Frau, in der er die Philosophie erkennt. http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Boethius,+Anicius+Manlius+Severinus/Die+Tr%C3%B6stungen+der+Philosophie/Erstes+Buch

Comment: @DavidVogt: Okay, wir sprechen also über einen lateinischen Text aus einer Zeit, in der man solche Abstraktionen wie die Geschichte häufig als Figuren, als Bilder oder Skulpturen um sich hatte, und die Vorstellung der Geschichte als Frau gängige Praxis war? Das hatte ich nicht auf dem Schirm. Für Personen, die sich oft mit derartigen Personifikationen befassen, ist die Bezeichnung *Lehrerin* dann auch naheliegend.